# How to hide column in AG-Grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-column

How to hide the column in AG-Grid and also it should not be displayed in Tool Panel...

```
var columnDefs = [{ headerName: "Stone_ID", field: "Stone_ID", width: 100, hide: "true" }]
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can set the column property of [suppressToolPanel](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-tool-panel/#suppressExample) to true to achieve that.

```
var columnDefs = [
    {
       headerName: "Stone_ID",
       field: "Stone_ID",
       width: 100,
       hide: true,
       suppressToolPanel: true
    }
]
```

Comment: is there a interface for columnDefs?  I haven't found one yet

Comment: @Winnemucca What do you mean by interface?

Comment: @Winnemucca https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-properties/

scroll down to the "columns only" section to see all available definitions

Comment: Can I prevent a column from appearing in the column menu ?

Comment: @eddy suppressToolPanel: true prevents a column from being an available option to group or pivot in the Columns side toolbar.

Comment: @Winnemucca there is an interface in the `ag-grid-community` package,  `interface ColDef extends AbstractColDef`.

Answer (score 47):

If you are looking for **dynamically** show/hide columns follow below:

> You can use either `setColumnVisible` or `setColumnsVisible`.

**NOTE:** those functions expect a colKey(s) which is related to the field you set in columnDefs.

```
columnDefs = [
    {
       headerName: "Name", 
       field: "name", // => that!
       width: 150
    },
    {
       headerName: "Last Name", 
       field: "last_name", // => that!
       width: 150
    },
    // ...
];
```

> **When using `setColumnVisible` you can show/hide a single column**

```
gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnVisible('name', false) //In that case we hide it
```

> **When using `setColumnsVisible` you can show/hide multiple columns**

```
gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnsVisible(['name', 'last_name'], true) //In that case we show them
```

Comment: Can I prevent a column from appearing in the column menu ?

Answer (score 14):

To do this programatically you can use:

Hide columns:

```
this.agGrid.columnApi.setColumnsVisible(["COL_ID_1", "COL_ID_2"], false);
```

Show columns:

```
this.agGrid.columnApi.setColumnsVisible(["COL_ID_1", "COL_ID_2"], true);
```

To do this for a whole column group you can use:

```
  const group = this.columnApi.getColumnGroup("MY_GROUP");
  group.children.forEach(child => this.columnApi.setColumnsVisible(child, false));
```

Comment: Can I prevent a column from appearing in the column menu ?

Answer (score 10):

Posting late but It may helpful for others with some extra details:

If you want to hide your column on the grid you can use `hide` property to hide that column from the grid.

**Only hide from grid colDef example:**

```
colMainDef = [
    {
      headerName: 'Approved',
      field: 'status',
      hide: true
    }]
```

But the same column will still be accessible on the side menu panel if you want to hide it from the side menu you can use one more property `suppressColumnsToolPanel` by making this true it will hide the column from the side menu.

**Hide column from the grid as well as from side panel colDef example:**

```
colMainDef = [
    {
      headerName: 'Approved',
      field: 'status',
      suppressColumnsToolPanel: true,
      hide: true,
    }]
```

Hope this will helps to `hide/show` columns as per your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

```
var columnDefs = [{ headerName: "Stone_ID", field: "Stone_ID", width: 100, hide: true }]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Can I prevent a column from appearing in the column menu ?

Answer (score 2):

hide: should get the value true, not the string "true" (like width: gets 100, not "100")

Comment: thank you for giving answer..But.. hide: "true"  this is working for hide the column from AG grid but this column appears in Toolpanel...My question is  if hide the column then it should not display value as well as it should not appear inTool Panel...

Answer (score 2):

```
{
  ...,
  hide: true,
  suppressColumnsToolPanel: true
}
```

In the package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^24.1.0",
    "@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules": "^24.1.0",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add "`hide: true`" in your column definition.

Ex:

```
var columnDefs = [{ headerName: "ABC", field: "XYZ", hide: true }]
```

Answer (score 0):

hide column on load
{
headerName: 'ROE',
field: 'roe',
width: 100,
hide: true
},

based on selection you can show/hide it using
example
this.gridColumnApi.setColumnVisible('roe',true);

Comment: What does this answer contribute beyond what other answers already state?

Answer (score 0):

We can hide column dynamically in the following way using **onColumnVisible** listen event

```
const onColumnVisible = useCallback(params => {
    if (params.source === 'toolPanelUi') {
        const colId = params.column ? [ params.column.colId ] : params.columns.map(col => col.colId)
        const value = columns.map(v => {
            if (v.colId === colId.find(c => c === v.colId)) {
                params.visible ? v.hide = false : v.hide = true
            }
            return v
        })
        if (value) {
            setColumns(value)
        }
    }
}, [ gridParams, setColumns ])

<Grid onColumnVisible={onColumnVisible } />
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML code

```
  <div>
    <label *ngFor="let col of columnDefs">
      <input type="checkbox" [checked]="!col.hide" (change)="toggleColumnVisibility(col)" /> {{col.headerName}}
    </label>
  </div>
```

The event function looks like this

```
  toggleColumnVisibility(column: any) {
    column.hide = !column.hide;
    this.agGrid.columnApi.setColumnVisible(column.field, !column.hide);
  }
```